# Finding Docker container processes? (from host point of view)

Tags: linux, docker, process-migration

I am doing some tests on docker and containers and I was wondering:

Is there a method I can use to find all process associated with a docker container by its name or ID *from the host point of view.*

After all, at the end of the day a container is a set of virtualized processes.

Comment: "a container is set of _virtualized processes_" or also _jailed processes_ -- which may be a little bit less abstract.

Answer (score 108):

You can use `docker top` command.
This command lists all processes running within your container.

For instance this command on a single process container on my box displays:

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                14097               13930               0                   23:17               pts/6               00:00:00            /bin/bash
```

All methods mentioned by others are also possible to use but this one should be easiest.

**Update**:

To simply get the main process id within the container use this command:

```
 docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' <container id>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - `docker top` is showing PIDs of processes running within the container, from the container's pid namespace. This user is asking for the PID of the container, from the host's perspective.

Answer (score 55):

Another way to get an overview of all Docker processes running on a host is using generic cgroup based systemd tools.

`systemd-cgls` will show all our cgroups and the processes running in them in a tree-view, like this:

```
├─1 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 21
├─docker
│ ├─070a034d27ed7a0ac0d336d72cc14671584cc05a4b6802b4c06d4051ce3213bd
│ │ └─14043 bash
│ ├─dd952fc28077af16a2a0a6a3231560f76f363359f061c797b5299ad8e2614245
│ │ └─3050 go-cron -s 0 0 * * * * -- automysqlbackup
```

As every Docker container has its own cgroup, you can also see Docker Containers and their corresponding host processes this way.

Two interesting properties of this method:

1. It works even if the Docker Daemon(s) are defunct.
2. It's a pretty quick overview.

You can also use `systemd-cgtop` to get an overview of the resource usage of Docker Containers, similar to `top`.

By the way: Since systemd services also correspond to cgroups these methods are also applicable to non-Dockerized systemd services.

Comment: This is the best answer, and it is a solution for a known issue with no solution: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12738 .  User needs to (1) find the pid id of the docker process, most easily identified by the port number associated with the container, and (2) find the pid of the associated containerid hash, and kill both.  Thanks for this tip.

Comment: Are the docker containers listed under `docker`?  In Docker version 18.09.4, systemd lists containers   under `containerd.service` not `docker.service`

Answer (score 30):

I found a similar solution using a bash script in one line:

```
for i in $(docker container ls --format "{{.ID}}"); do docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}} {{.Name}}' $i; done
```

Comment: extremely useful and clean solution

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Xargs works faster:
docker container ls --format "{{.ID}}" | xargs docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}} {{.Name}}'

Answer (score 23):

the process run in a docker container is a child of a process named `containerd-shim` (in Docker v18.09.4)

- First figure out the process IDs of the `containerd-shim` processes.
- For each of them, find their child process.

---

```sh
pgrep containerd-shim
```

> ```
> 7105
> 7141
> 7248
> ```

To find the child process of parent process 7105:

```sh
pgrep -P 7105
```

> 7127

---

In the end you could get the list with:

```sh
for i in $(pgrep containerd-shim); do pgrep -P $i; done
```

> ```
> 7127
> 7166
> 7275
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Thomasleveil

Comment: If a visual tree is enough you can also use `ps -axfo pid,ppid,uname,cmd`

Comment: I was wondering what is the purpose of "keeping only processes that parent process ID is the one of the docker daemon"? The only child of dockerd process is docker-proxy. The containers are not shows as descendants of dockerd process.

Comment: @Tim this answer is more than 3 years old, things might have changed

Comment: Can you verify if things have changed?

Comment: It's not a good idea to rely on internal implementation details (i.e. some internal process name that may change at any time). The other answers are much better since they use documented APIs

Answer (score 6):

When running this on the host, it will give you a list of processes running in a container with `<Container ID>`, showing host PIDs instead of container PIDs.

```sh
DID=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' <Container ID>);ps --ppid $DID -o pid,ppid,cmd
```

Comment: does not work on my server. however `systemd-cgls` works

Answer (score 5):

`docker ps` will list docker containers that are running.

`docker exec <id|name> ps` will tell you the processes it's running.

Comment: This will present processes from container point of view i want to find processes from host point of view and for more misunderstandings i will edit the question.

Comment: I would suggest including an example of why - because typically, there isn't much need.

Comment: Process migration tests

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 4):

Building on @zangw's work, I wanted the container name and image as well.
(pstree can be found by installing `psmisc`)

```bash
for i in $(docker container ls --format "{{.ID}}|{{.Names}}|{{.Image}}"); do printf $i | awk -F '|' '{str = sprintf("%s %s %s %s", "conatiner_name: ", $2, "| image_name:", $3)} END {print str}'; printf $i | awk -F '|' '{print $1}' | xargs -I'{}' docker top {} -o pid | awk '!/PID/' | xargs -I'{}' pstree -psa {}; done
```

or will pipe to less (/myterm to search + enter, then 'n' for next entry and 'N' for previous entry.)

```bash
for i in $(docker container ls --format "{{.ID}}|{{.Names}}|{{.Image}}"); do printf $i | awk -F '|' '{str = sprintf("%s %s %s %s", "conatiner_name: ", $2, "| image_name:", $3)} END {print str}'; printf $i | awk -F '|' '{print $1}' | xargs -I'{}' docker top {} -o pid | awk '!/PID/' | xargs -I'{}' pstree -psa {}; done | less
```

Sample output on CentOS 7:

```
conatiner_name:  myproject_chrome_1 | image_name: selenium/standalone-chrome:4.5.2-20221021
    systemd,1 --switched-root --system --deserialize 22
      `-containerd-shim,24700 -namespace moby -id d22cd987862ed0d7c09431d12e2c8e4061f688a3401d1c1188458cbabe11a324 -address/run/
          `-bash,24727 /opt/bin/entry_point.sh
              `-supervisord,24828 /usr/bin/supervisord --configuration /etc/supervisord.conf
                  |-bash,24924 /opt/bin/start-xvfb.sh
                  |   `-xvfb-run,24933 /usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-num=99 --listen-tcp...
                  |       |-Xvfb,24964 :99 -screen 0 1360x1020x24 -fbdir /var/tmp -dpi 96 -listen tcp -noreset -ac +extension RANDR ...
                  |       `-fluxbox,25023 -display :99.0
                  |-bash,24925 /opt/bin/start-vnc.sh
                  |   `-x11vnc,25134 -usepw -forever -shared -rfbport 5900 -rfbportv6 5900 -display :99.0
                  |-bash,24926 /opt/bin/start-novnc.sh
                  |   `-bash,24932 /opt/bin/noVNC/utils/launch.sh --listen 7900 --vnc localhost:5900
                  |       `-python3,24955 -m websockify --web /opt/bin/noVNC/utils/../ 7900 localhost:5900
                  `-bash,24927 -c /opt/bin/start-selenium-standalone.sh && kill -s SIGINT `cat /var/run/supervisor/supervisord.pid`
                      `-bash,24928 /opt/bin/start-selenium-standalone.sh
                          `-java,25037 -Dwebdriver.http.factory=jdk-http-client -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server.jar --ext...
                              |-{java},25058
                              |-{java},25060
```

Comment: This is really good. The `systemd-cgls` solution did what I wanted, and is certainly easier, but this has the advantage of _naming_ the containers. With `systemd-cgls`, I still needed to analyze all the processes in the container to figure out which container it was.

Answer (score 3):

Since the following command shows only the container's itself process ID (not all child processes):

```
docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}'  <container-name_or_ID>
```

To find a process that is the child of a container, this process ID must be find in directory /proc. So find "processID" inside it and then find the container hash from file:

```
/proc/parent_process/task/processID
```

and then **cut** container ID from hash (first 12-digits of the container hash) and then find the container itself:

```
#!/bin/bash 
processPath=$(find /proc/ -name $1 2>/dev/null) 
containerID=$(cat ${processPath}/cgroup | fgrep 'pids:/docker/' | sed -e 's#.*/docker/##g' | cut -c 1-12) 
docker ps | fgrep $containerID
```

Save above script in a file such as: **p2c** and run it by:

```
p2c <PID>
```

For example:

```
p2c 85888
```

Comment: it's not working

cat: /proc/80300: Is a directory

Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...

Try 'grep --help' for more information.

Comment: Try:
`processPath=$(find /proc/ -name $1 2>/dev/null | tail -n1); containerID=$(cat ${processPath}/cgroup | egrep 'docker.*\.scope' -o | cut -c 8-19);  docker ps | fgrep $containerID;` instead

Answer (score 1):

There are scenarios where the docker service on the container itself becomes unresponsive, so `docker inspect` stops responding. If that happens, you can use `procps` to search for your container's PID. You can easily list all containers launched with `docker run` like this (you might need to match a different pattern if you are using compose or another orchestration framework):

```bash
ps aux | grep 'docker run'
```

Then you can kill your container with `kill -9 <container_pid>` (`SIGKILL`) You will also need to restart docker daemon (IE `service docker restart`) after doing this for it to "deregister" your container.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `docker container` and `docker top`

```
docker ps --format "{{.ID}}" | xargs -I'{}' docker top {} -o pid | awk '!/PID/'
```

Note: `awk '!/PID/'` just remove the `PID` header from the output of `docker top`

---

If you want to know the whole process tree of docker container, you can try it

```
docker ps --format "{{.ID}}" | xargs -I'{}' docker top {} -o pid | awk '!/PID/' | xargs -I'{}' pstree -psa {}
```

Answer (score -4):

Docker stats "container id" 
Shows the resource consumption along with pid or simply Docker ps .

Probably this cheat sheet can be of use.
http://theearlybirdtechnology.com/2017/08/12/docker-cheatsheet/