# How to record the peak memory usage of a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I'm running a number of short-lived docker containers each of which does some memory-intensive batch processing. I'm looking for a way to find the *peak* memory usage each container hit while it was running. Knowing this will allow me to optimize the infrastructure I run these containers on for future runs.

One naive way to achieve this is redirecting the streaming output of `docker stats` to some file: `docker stats container_id > stats.log`. However, this requires running a process for each container and then sorting through very verbose logs to find the peak usage. I'm wondering if there's not an easier way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are interested in the process with `PID=1` inside the container, you can find the `PID` this process has on the host and then use:

```
grep VmPeak /proc/$PID/status
```

---

Example with a `mongo` container:

This container has a single process:

```
$ docker container exec -it mongo top -bn 1
top - 10:04:51 up 32 min,  0 users,  load average: 0.36, 0.52, 0.55
Tasks:   2 total,   1 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  6.1 us,  2.0 sy,  0.3 ni, 90.6 id,  0.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  6103572 total,  2642744 free,  1352032 used,  2108796 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1942896 total,  1942896 free,        0 used.  4277928 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   64 root      20   0   38624   3116   2724 R   6.7  0.1   0:00.89 top
    1 mongodb   20   0 1094540  80100  35916 S   0.0  1.3   0:22.51 mongod
```

To get the `PID` of this process from the host's perspective:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' mongo
2532
```

and finally:

```
$ grep VmPeak /proc/2532/status
VmPeak:  1094540 kB
```

---

Links:

- [Peak memory usage of a linux/unix process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774556/peak-memory-usage-of-a-linux-unix-process)
- [Peak memory usage of a process](https://serverfault.com/questions/11550/peak-memory-usage-of-a-process)
- [Finding Docker container processes? (from host point of view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878808/finding-docker-container-processes-from-host-point-of-view)

Comment: `grep: /proc/36133/status: No such file or directory` on macOS

Comment: Looks like on macOS you can obtain this data by reading the /proc thing inside the container.

Answer (score 3):

`docker stats` has the `--format` option to customize the output. For example we can output only memory usage:

```
 docker stats --no-stream --format '{{.MemUsage}}' CONTAINER_ID 
516KiB / 8GiB
```

`CONTAINER_ID` in the command must be replaced with the ID of our container (which we can get with `docker ps`).

516KiB is the current memory usage of the container and 8GiB is the maximum memory that the container is allowed to use.

On GNU/Linux, we can filter out the memory usage from the output with `cut` and redirect the output into a file:

```
docker stats --no-stream --format '{{.MemUsage}}' CONTAINER_ID | cut -d '/' -f 1 >>docker-stats
```

Finally, we can put this command into a while loop and add a one second delay between iterations:

```
while true; do docker stats --no-stream --format '{{.MemUsage}}' CONTAINER_ID | cut -d '/' -f 1 >>docker-stats; sleep 1; done
```

This way, in the `docker-stats` file, we will get a list of memory usage values of the container with one second resolution. Of course, if a peak lasts less than one second we may miss it.

[Docker stats docs.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats)