# Is it possible to share PID namespace between multiple containers?

Tags: docker

I have 3 containers: `containerA`, `containerB`, `containerC`. I have no control over them.

I'm working on a fourth container that contains a sampling profiler and therefore needs access to processes inside other containers. Previously, when I needed to access only `containerA` I used the command `docker run --security-opt="apparmor=unconfined" --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --pid=container:12345abc --rm -it --entrypoint bash mycontainer` and it worked as expected. Now, I need to be able to access processes from all 3 containers. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A container only has a single PID namespace: you can (as you show in your question) have one container use the PID namespace of another container, but there's no way to provide a container with access to multiple PID namespaces.

One option would be to run all four containers in the same PID namespace, e.g:

```
docker run --name containerA ...
docker run --name containerB --pid container:containerA ...
docker run --name containerC --pid container:containerA ...
docker run --name containerD --pid container:containerA ...
```

A second option would be to run your profiling container in the *host* pid namespace, in which case it would be able to see processes running in all of the other containers...but it would have the host view of the pids rather than the container view:

```
docker run --pid host ...
```

You would need to figure out how to map host pids to the corresponding containers. One mechanism is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48922355/147356), but there are other ways of going about this.